# Hyperlink is not working

Tags: html, anchor

I have the below code, however the Contact us button is not working, please advise:

```
<nav class="pull-left">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0s"><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".1s"><a href="#app_features">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".1s"> <a href="Contact.html"> Contact us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".1s"><a href="terms.html" target="_blank">Terms of use</a>
        </li>
        <li class="animated wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".1s"><a href="#app_features">Privacy policy</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you have a file named `Contact.html` in the same directory as the file you posted here?

Answer (score 0):

Colud you please try by this way

```
<li data-wow-delay=".1s"> <a href="Contact.html"> Contact us</a></li>
```

I mean remove the class="animated wow fadeInLeft" from li tag. 
I think it will happen for JQuery class or function, which are called by class="animated wow fadeInLeft"